# Opacify function returning unmodified hex

Tags: css, sass

I seem to have run into something strange with sass. I'm trying to get a 95% opaque version of `#111111` but it seems that the `opacify` function isn't returning the correct value. When I use the code below, the compiled stylesheet sets the `background-color` to `#111111`. I'm using `opacify` because the color is being stored as a variable in hex and cannot be modified through standard `rgba` if I want to continue using the variables. Code below:

```
$midnight: #111111;

.some-container {
  background-color: opacify($midnight,0.95);
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`opacify` *increases* opacity.  You want [`transparentize()`](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#transparentize-instance_method):

```
background-color: transparentize($midnight, 0.05);
```

Comment: ah! simple _English_ got me this time :)